# Can I change a website address that uses OpenID for authentication, without loosing the users?

Tags: openid

My doubt is the following. I have a website, where the users authenticate using OpenID and others system like Facebook, Twitter.

I notted, that every user registered using something like OpenId, gets a KEY that is a URL or a code.

If in the future, I change my website url, will these users be able yet to loggin my website yet?